# MVVM - From Model to ViewModel leaving Model untouched

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dispatcher

Let's say I have a third-party back-end [C# .NET Standard] library representing my Model; this library is used purely as a data processing back-end tool.
Clearly no GUI, only some public readonly registers are provided in order to allow other parent/owning code to observe the status of those registers. As a simple example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int MyVariable { get; private set; }
    public List<int> MyCollection { get; private set; }
    ...
}
```

Now I'd like to provide a WPF application acting as a view-panel/dashboard so that a user can see on a monitor the live situation; I opted for a MVVM approach.

First questions are: **is it a correct design approach to assume Model should be left untouched, without adapting it to ViewModel (forgetting Model is a third-party library the code of I actually don't possess)? how can I efficiently and correctly write ViewModel so that it can extract/retrieve those registers from Model?**
I have gone through a time-based update option (each second re-reading those registers from Model), which honestly seems a little bit unefficient; I can't figure out how to intercept Model variable changing or Model collection changing from ViewModel side.

Then, let's drop for a moment the constraint I don't possess library code and consider I can modify Model (again, is it a correct design?). I would make `MyModel` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and change `List<int> MyCollection`  into `ObservableCollection<int> MyCollection` so that I can intercept data changing and have binding to update at screen. But then I fall into `Dispatcher` issue when the `CollectionChanged` event got fired. **How can I perform collection update since Model has no access to Dispatcher (.NET Standard)? How can I suppress CollectionChanged fired by Model and fire it from ViewModel inside Dispatcher?**
I have gone through a `Dispatcher` forwarding solution but again I think this is somehow wrong, not properly coded:

```
public delegate void DispatcherService(Action action);
public class MyModel
{
    public int MyVariable { get; private set; }
    public List<int> MyList { get; private set; }
    public event DispatcherService MyDispatcherService;
    public void AddElementToMyList(int element)
    {
        MyDispatcherService?.Invoke(() => MyList.Add(element));
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    private MyModel _myModel;
    public int MyModelMyVariable { get { return _myModel.MyVariable; } }
    public List<int> MyModelMyCollection { get { return _myModel.MyCollection; } }
    public MyViewModel(MyModel myModel)
    {
        _myModel = myModel;
        _myModel.MyDispatcherService += ((action) => { Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action); });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way anything could tell something in a register list changed? as described tgese sound like something you can only poll. How much do these integers vary from second to second? How many are processedba second?  Is your view going to be a blur or does maybe one item change in a second, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your model classes don't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChaged` and `INotifyCollectionChanged`. This are interfaces that are meant to be implemented by view model classes to provide very general notifications for the view. The model should expose specialized events to notify the view model about data changes.

Since the library is 3rd party, you can only use it the way the API allows it to be used. When the library exposes dynamic data, it will most likely expose related events to which your view model can subscribe to.
Otherwise your view model would have to poll the library for data changes (in this case you may look for a more serious alternative library).

In MVVM the model should never deal with any `Dispatcher`. `Dispatcher` is a UI related concept. It deals with the UI thread affinity of UI objects (`DispatcherObject`). It is also responsible to manage the job queue of the UI thread.
The model component has neither UI related objects nor does it rely on an UI or UI thread.

In your described scenario the correct approach would be to subscribe to the model events from your view model. Then populate a `ObservableCollection`, which the view model exposes to the view for data binding.

According to MVVM the model does never access the view model. Therefore it is only the view model that has to do the marshaling of the `CollectionChanged` event or any other access to an object, which is associated with the UI thread (e.g., in case the access occurred from a different thread than the UI thread).

Your corrected example could look like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public int Property { get; private set; }
  public List<int> DataCollection { get; private set; }
  public event EventHandler DataIsReady;

  public void AddElementToDataCollectionOnBackgroundThread(int element)
  {
    Task.Run(()  
    {
      this.DataCollection.Add(element);         
      DataIsReady?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanegd
{
  private MyModel Model { get; };
 
  private int viewModelProperty;
  public int ViewModelProperty
  {
    get => return this.viewModelProperty;
    set 
    {
      this.viewModelProperty = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ObservaleCollection<int> ViewItemsSource { get }

  public MyViewModel(MyModel model)
  {
    this.Model = model;
    this.Model.DataIsReady += OnModelDataIsReady;
  } 

  private void OnModelDataIsReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Since the event was raised on a background thread,
    // the view model is responsible to marshal the collection change to the UI thread
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
      () =>
      {
        this.ViewItemsSource.Clear();
        this.Model.DataCollection.ForEach(this.ViewItemsSource.Add));
      });

    // PropertyChanged is automatically marshalled 
    // to the UI thread by the framework --> no dispatcher needed
    this.ViewModelProperty = this.Model.Property;
  }
}
```

Comment: your code seems very clear and smooth to me, there is just one single point that I'd like to ask clarification on: is it ok to perform clear&refill on ```ViewItemsSource``` each time ```DataIsReady``` event got fired? can this present performance issues (in the case of a very long list or a very high-rate updated list)?

Comment: Yes, clear&refill can degrade performance, especially when a control binds to this collection. The control has to render again to display the changes. For this reason you always strive to use UI virtualization, maybe in combination with data virtualization. This way you can control the impact collection changes will have on the UI of. If the modified collection is not a binding source of the view, you can consider the performance impact negligible in most cases.

Comment: In this case (where the collection does not serve as a data source for the view) you could refresh the collection on a background thread (which may introduce concurrency issues). For huge collections you may introduce a more fine grained event logic. But as mentioned before, huge collections are mostly not necessary, as the user can only view a very limited number of items. Collection size should be reduced using data virtualization. This was just an example, mainly focusing to show the dispatcher at work for `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: yes, UI virtualization sounds as a good option

Comment: just one last clarification: is it good design for *ViewModel* properties (those required/bound to the *View*) to reference *ViewModel* "mirror variables/fields"  instead of referencing those defined in the *Model* (based on your example, ```ViewModelProperty``` referencing ```viewModelProperty``` instead of ```Model.Property``` and ```ViewItemsSource``` referencing itself insted of ```Model.DataCollection```)? on the one hand this seems to me as bit of code duplication, on the other this seems to me as good decoupling

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly OK for your model to be a wrapper around some library objects. In a perfect world, those library objects would be so full-featured that they would support observation patterns such as `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Then they could be used in all sorts of contexts, such as directly being the model of your MVVM. In your case, since the library objects don't support observability, it may make sense for you to create wrapper classes that provide that observability. Otherwise, you'll end up compensating for that in your view-model (which is also perfectly acceptable, although I like my scopes to be very clean when defining architectural boundaries).

As for the dispatcher thing, my instinct is that a model should not exhibit any thread affinity -- if something updates the model on a thread, notifications go out on that same thread. Since views are inherently thread-bound, the responsibility for marshaling notifications would either be in the view-model or the directly in the view. Of course, you could always marshal the call which updates the model, so that notifications are only occurring on the UI thread.

Comment: Regarding the first item what approach do you suggest for providing observability: time-based update or something different? Regarding the second item I am ok when you state 'if something updates the model on a thread, notifications go out on that same thread' but then I can't find a way to properly handle this situation through ```Dispatcher```, can you please provide a quick and simple example?

Comment: @GiacomoPirinoli Depends. Are these objects being modified under your control, or outside of your control? If outside, the only option is polling (time-based update). If it's within your control, I would never recommend polling. You could instead create wrapper classes or -- in the worst case -- directly make method calls or fire events between objects in your view-model.

Comment: @GiacomoPirinoli If I recall correctly, WPF automatically dispatches IPropertyChanged/ICollectionChanged notifications to the UI thread. Are you seeing something different? If the notifications are being received by code that you are writing (as opposed to being received by WPF bindings), then you'll have to marshal at the receiving site.

Comment: Well if I simply perform update in my Model library (example: public void Add(T item)) without any specific handling, the CollectionChanged event gets fired and then I get the Exception 'This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.'

Comment: The model is however your data is surfaced. I would say it's far from perfect for a model object to implement inotifypropertychanged. They should not be presented directly to a view. This is the purpose of a viewmodel. There are three layers in the pattern not two.

Comment: And. Inotifypropertychanged marshalls propertychanged notifications to the ui thread. So if you did implement inpc on a model object ( very dirty ) you would not need to marshall any notifications.

Comment: @Andy I sometimes use INotifyPropertyChanged to keep my view-model in sync with my model, just like WPF uses INotifyPropertyChanged keeps the view in sync with the view-model. It's particularly useful when multiple views are displaying elements from the same model. In some implementations, this might be done using DataSet, which has its own notification paradigm that the view-model can tap into.

Comment: @Andy I'm sure this is what you meant, but INotifyPropertyChanged itself doesn't do the marshaling. The binding layer or WPF widgets do, I forget. INotifyPropertyChanged is just an interface.

Comment: @MichaelGunter Would you recommend using an ObservableCollection in your model to listen to on the viewmodel side? Otherwise an event would work, but require that every change on the list<t> would then invoke the event. Thus basically the same functionality with extra steps.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer I use `ObservableCollection` in my models all the time. The only thing to keep in mind is if it's the right level of granularity for your model operations. If a particular model operation does something like update 3 lists, then you may want to notify only when the entire change is complete. These are design decisions that have to be made on a case-by-case basis.